What's up with the Halloween theme?
The front page of Chinese @ SE is looking like this for me today:



The orange is giving me big Halloween vibes.
Any ideas what's going on here?

This is mentioned on Why did all sites turn orange? on meta.SE:

Fixed!
We’ve got a new theming API in Stacks that was leaking a bit. Funnily enough, all the themes we happened to test via smoke tests already had orange buttons so we didn't catch it.
Aaron Shekey ♦

It seems to be a work in progress.
